# How to digitally sign an assembly in Visual Studion 2010 and above?

Tags: .net, security, visual-studio-2012, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I came across the explanation of strong name vs digital signature of an assembly on this blog post: [strong name vs digital signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/03/what-s-the-difference-part-five-certificate-signing-vs-strong-naming.aspx).
The MSDN help only shows the strong signature part [How to sign an assembly with a Strong Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) without specifying how to digitally sign the assembly. 
My two questions are:

Once we have a digital certificate from a CA and we have the certificate in the Windows store, how can we digitally sign an assembly?
  and 
 Will the CLR automatically do this verification whenever the assembly is invoked, for example if the assembly is an executable and once the assembly is digitally signed, the assembly is deployed to another machine, will the CLR verify the signature before executing the assembly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can a strong name be generated from a digital certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To digitally sign an assembly use [SignTool.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. CLR doesn't check and doesn't verify digital signatures.